# Suggest duplicates when posting a question from iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, similar-questions

From the desktop, any new question has a list of suggested duplicates between the title and the body. From personal experience, this has stopped me from posting several duplicate questions.

Can we get this feature in the iOS app?

Perhaps replace the body input area with the list while the title is focused. You can still see the text in the rendered area to the right, so that's not a problem.

Comment: Yeah, you *definetly* need it. ;)